# Double Eigenvalue by calculation matrix Exponential

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Yea, I had no luck. Drawing the eigenvalues of $A = \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \quad 3 \\ 0\quad1\end{array}\right)$ I get $\lambda_{1,2} = 1$. Hence $A -\lambda\,I = \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \quad 3 \\ 0\quad0\end{array}\right)$. If I remember right from Calculus 1 the Kernel of this thing is having Dimension 1. That sounds inconvenient. Thus the Eigenspace would be 1 dimension...

What I'm trying to do: Calculation Matrix Exponential of A.

Comment: I can't actually tell what your question is. Are you trying to compute the matrix exponential of $A$? If so, write $A=I+3N$ and consider what powers of $A^n$ look like.

Comment: looks like $A^n = \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \quad n\,3 \\ 0\quad1\end{array}\right)$. But since $n$ goes to $\infty$ in Matrix Exponential I can't  really take use of that?

Comment: Sure you can. To simplify notation, you have $A^n=I+3nN$. You have $$\exp(A)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}A^n =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(I+3n N).$$ Now resum the series.

Comment: yea, that's what I tried to recognize. Ah, hang on. If u mean by N  $\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \quad 3 \\ 0\quad 0 \end{array}\right)$ then $\exp(N) = I +N$ and $\exp(I) = e \cdot I$. But how do I combine that?

Comment: That works too. (I meant $N=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ but the point is the same.) In that case you want to use the fact that, if $AB=BA$, then $e^{A+B}=e^A e^B$.

Comment: so to conclude: $\exp(A) = e\,\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \quad 0 \\ 0\quad 1 \end{array}\right) \cdot \left(\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \quad 0 \\ 0\quad 1 \end{array}\right) + \left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \quad 3 \\ 0\quad 0 \end{array}\right)  \right)$. Eh, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118544/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-leon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find $f(A)$ for a holomorphic function $f$ defined on some neighbourhood of $1$, you need to find a polynomial $p \in \Bbb{C}[x]$ of degree $< 2$ such that
$$p(1) = f(1), \quad p'(1) = f'(1)$$
and then $f(A)=p(A)$.
Trying out $p(x) = ax+b$, we find that $p(x) = ex$ is the desired polynomial if $f$ is the exponential function.

Therefore
$$e^A = p(A) = eA = \pmatrix{e & 3e \\ 0 & e}.$$